# How pair codes are generated for devices with no browser support (OAuth 2.0)?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, device, key-pair

I am currently implementing an OAuth 2.0 provider and I wish to support devices with no browser support like consoles and TVs! I took as example the YouTube pair for my smart TV, which generated the 8 letters code PJGV-SJBQ! How and where (server or device) this code is generated and how to guarantee it is unique?! I meant: at server I think that code is searched and to the logged user the device permission is granted, right?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the RFC6749, there is no grant type flow for such devices. 
You have to create a custom grant type flow. 
Look at this flow described for Google API: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#device

I hope it will help you.